# CakePHP created and modified columns for MS SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, cakephp

It appears that my automatic CakePHP table columns - created and modified - are causing an error when I migrated to Microsoft SQL Server 2005. I found this [old ticket](https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/5241), but nothing that seemed to resolve the issue.

Here is the error:

```
Warning (512): SQL Error: Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.
[CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 673]

[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 83

Query: INSERT INTO [user_log] ([created], [user_id]) VALUES ('NULL', 1)
```

This is my schema:

```
created datetime NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_user_log_created] DEFAULT (NULL),
```

I also tried:

```
created datetime NULL,
```

Any direction would be appreciated. Running Cake 1.3 and MS SQL 2005.

Comment: If you're sure you've set up everything correctly and this is a clearly reproducible bug using the latest Cake release, you should open a ticket for it at http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to call it a bug. And it looks like someone did post a ticket before. I feel like it has to be something I am missing in my table definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I was indeed mistaken. I reread the [old ticket](https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/5241) and even though I had tried both column schema definitions, I forgot to flush the model cache in tmp/

So for clarity and in case anyone else makes my same mistake:

```
created datetime NULL,
modified datetime NULL,
```

Are the appropriate column definitions for MS SQL, **and be sure to flush your model cache**.